# Bootstrap 4 not rendering completely reactjs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have searched for Bootstrap 4 templates of a navbar with login and I came across [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/PljEeB5dN3/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-login-form). So, I have converted it and this is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
                <div className="container">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Reddit</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
                        &#9776;
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item"><a href="/" className="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                            <li className="nav-item"><a href="/" className="nav-link">Popular</a></li>
                            <li className="nav-item"><a href="/" className="nav-link">All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav flex-row justify-content-between ml-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item order-2 order-md-1"><a href="/" className="nav-link" title="settings"><i className="fa fa-cog fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                            <li className="dropdown order-1">
                                <button type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" className="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">Login <span className="caret"></span></button>
                                <ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mt-2">
                                <li className="px-3 py-2">
                                    <form className="form">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input id="emailInput" placeholder="Email" className="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" required="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" className="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" required="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group text-center">
                                                <small><a href="/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPassword">Forgot password?</a></small>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default HeaderComponent;
```

The problem here is the dropdown of the login option is not getting rendered. And when I minimize the window, all the options are hidden but pressing the button doesnt **uncollapse** the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that probably you have something with an higher z-index because your code currently works in the React JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9g7683t/

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

I've imported all Bootstrap scripts (maybe can help).

The code is a copy and paste of your component render.

Comment: I have imported bootstrap in `index.js` in this way: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`Now where should I write those statements. Should I write them in `index.html` file?(Adding in `index.html` didn't help). Also I didn't manually change any z-index values so where do I look for them?

Comment: You can download Bootstrap files even from the source link or you can paste the link and script in your index.html (from here: https://getbootstrap.com/). See network requests with the browser and ensure that you have no problem with these links.

Comment: So, I have copied the link and script into `index.html` and its working fine in `localhost:8000` run by django but not in `localhost:3000` running react. Why?

Comment: @SreekarMouli I can't know why :) Ensure you are using the correct index.html and ensure that each project has his links and scripts (as you can see there is an integrity check, try to copy from the website and paste in the react project scripts and links with the new integrity). Ensure that request is not blocked in your network request!